# SSH error when trying to connect to laravel forge database with mysql workbench (can connect fine through a console)

Tags: mysql, laravel, ssh, mysql-workbench, forge

I'm having trouble connecting to my database through mysql workbench even though I can do it through a console. It doesn't seem like I'm even getting past ssh because this is my error

[image]

Here are my connection settings:

```
Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH

SSH Hostname: DropletIP:22

SSH Username: forge

SSH Key File: C:\Users\username\.ssh\id_rsa

MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1

MySQL Server Port: 3306

Username: forge
```

The workbench is version 8 and the mysql version on the droplet is version 8.

I've tried switch all kinds of stuff around like removing the port on the ssh hostname, trying the public ssh key instead of the private, and changing the mysql hostname to the DropletIP. None of these worked.

Not really sure why this is happening. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you emtered the wrong user name password combination for the ssh(it can't be none) check the mysql conection.

Comment: @nbk If I log into the server with forge@IP then they SSH username should be forge right? Also for the ssh password I am putting in the password that I type after running the forge@IP command and it's not working.

Comment: no the username is without  @ip in workbench, but in your original error message stands username none. u should fill the field in the connection manager

Comment: @nbk yeah I do just have forge as the username, but it's still coming through as "none" for whatever reason

Comment: Make a new connection and try again. i used it with workbench 6.3 and 8,0 and it works fine.